# What PayPal API do sites like Harvest and Freshbooks use to accept payments on behalf of their users?

Tags: paypal

It looks like both sites (Freshbooks and Harvest) are able to accept PayPal payments on behalf of their users by only collecting the user's PayPal email address and the payment goes directly to the user (rather than flowing through Freshbooks and Harvest's own accounts). What PayPal API enables this?

I do not see any indication this is possible in the current API documentation 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

The Express Checkout APIs will allow that.  You can use the SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID parameter to specify where the payment should go.

**Update for 2022**:  PayPal now has their new "Complete Payments" API.  It allows you to onboard 3rd party users into your app, and then you can do whatever you need on behalf of their account for them.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, braintree being a `Paypal Service`, this is likely the `API` that you are looking for: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/